# Inserting data into database in asp.net froms using the get method

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net

I want to insert data into a database directly using the url. Asp.net by default utilises the post method but we can mention which method we want to use because post method is secured.
In get method the data is send in the url to the database.

I am getting this:

```
http://localhost:37145/WebSite6/Default.aspx?__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEzMTc4NjY3NThkZH%2FzblWG%2FaetOcaD3rJQBa9MpAmvbemwH%2FV9X6BPkAeu&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAN9lGp6YeH%2BodzmCfidl9y1ESCFkFW%2FRuhzY1oLb%2FNUVM34O%2FGfAV4V4n0wgFZHr3f%2FBbzXLqOVQaj%2FDSazKtEluAReRoZhIKn64XnVVI%2Fuvg%3D%3D&TextBox1=admin&Button1=Button
```

In the above url there are two things _viewstate and _eventvalidation what are these two things and at the end value from a textbox and button is appended to the url and the data is inserted into the database.

Also is there any method to get the data inside _viewstate by code because i want to insert data into the databae directly using the url and get method.

Also can i get a response from the database whether the data has been inserted successfully or not.
Like 1 if successfully inserted or,
0 if failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
mydata=Request.QueryString("TextBox1")
```

then you can insert mydata content into your database.

Answer (score 0):

Set `EnableEventValidation="false" EnableViewState="false"` in your .aspx page.This will eliminate  __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION from the url.

Then In the .aspx.cs file get the data from the url using

`var mydata1 = Request.QueryString[0]`    //for your first data
`var mydata2 = Request.QueryString[1]`    //for your second data

and then Insert the using Insert Command of SQL.

Hope that will help you.